# Avconv - misunderstanding file names with FPS

Tags: ubuntu, avconv

I have these series of file names:

```
00001_2013-10-03_07-01-00.png  00007_2013-10-03_07-07-00.png  00013_2013-10-03_07-13-00.png
00002_2013-10-03_07-02-00.png  00008_2013-10-03_07-08-00.png  00014_2013-10-03_07-14-00.png
00003_2013-10-03_07-03-00.png  00009_2013-10-03_07-09-00.png  00015_2013-10-03_07-15-00.png
00004_2013-10-03_07-04-00.png  00010_2013-10-03_07-10-00.png  00016_2013-10-03_07-16-00.png
00005_2013-10-03_07-05-00.png  00011_2013-10-03_07-11-00.png
00006_2013-10-03_07-06-00.png  00012_2013-10-03_07-12-00.png
```

What I am trying to do in Avconv is join them altogether into a video where each video is 15fps. Its a build up of an animation.

So far after some reading I have got this:

```
avconv -r 10 image2 -i 000%d_2013-10-03_07-%d-00.png test.avi
```

Not perfect I know, and it does not work, i get the error:

```
000%d_2013-10-03_07-%d-00.png: No such file or directory
```

How do I tell avconv the right file structure. And if I wanted the output of the video to be 15fps, how would I do this.

This is the version I am running

```
avconv version v9-2267-ga3fabc6, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Oct 14 2013 19:29:05 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The image2 demuxer doesn't support complex patterns like these. The most straightforward way around this is to concatenate the images in the order you want them and pipe them to avconv, using the `image2pipe` demuxer. I.e. something like `cat *.png|avconv -c:v png -f image2pipe -i - <encoding options> ....`.

To use a different framerate, just pass a different number to the `-r` option.